# Python Data Import

Tags: python, import, line-breaks

I am using the following code to import data in Python:

```
 one=[]
 two=[]
 three=[]
 four=[]
 five=[]
 six=[]
 x=0
 for line in open('text.txt', 'r'):
     if x==2:
         column0, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 = line.split(',')
 else:
    column0, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 = line.split(' ')
    one.append(column0)
    two.append(column1)
    three.append(column2)
    four.append(column3)
    five.append(column4)
    six.append(column5)
    x=x+1
```

This code imports this text file:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 
 1 2 3 4 5 6 
 1,2,3,4,5,6
 1 2 3 4 5 6
 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

But I am having so much trouble with how to import the following

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 
 1 2 3 4 5 6 
 1,2,3,
 4,5,6 
 1 2 3 4 5 6
 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Even though the data has a break on the third line I want it to import the same way as the first text file. I tried importing by row and then using the number of variables for the third row but I could not get it to work.

Does anyone know of any resources or examples or that can help? Thanks!

Comment: is there always supposed to be six items per set

Comment: I think i see what he is asking. He wants to load every 6th element into the respective arrays.

Comment: Every six elements, not every sixth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heres one way to get the lines right ... Its not a complete answer but i think it addresses whatever your problem might be

```
fh  = open('Documents/import.txt').read()

for line in fh.split('\n'):
    print line.strip()
    splits = line.split()
    if  len(splits) ==1 and splits[0]== line.strip():
        splits = [item for item in line.strip().split(',') if item]
    print splits
```

whoops ... didnt read what you wanted try this

```
fh  = open('Documents/import.txt').read()
the_list = []
for line in fh.split('\n'):
    print line.strip()
    splits = line.split()
    if  len(splits) ==1 and splits[0]== line.strip():
        splits = line.strip().split(',')
    if splits:the_list.append(splits)

for i in range(len(the_list)):
    print the_list[i]
    if  the_list[i][-1]=='':
        the_list[i].pop(-1)
        the_list[i].extend(the_list[i+1])
        i += 1

print the_list
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you added the second for loop:     `for i in range(len(the_list)):  
    print the_list[i]  
    if  the_list[i][-1]=='':  
        the_list[i].pop(-1)  
        the_list[i].extend(the_list[i+1])  
        i += 1`

Answer (score 1):

1. You've asked nine questions on StackOverflow and only accepted an answer to one of them? Please show your appreciation for the kindness of strangers and [accept some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).
2. Saying "I tried it and it doesn't work" is good, but **how** did it fail to work? What was the error message? If the program behaved unexpectedly, what did you actually expect?
3. For reading comma (space?) separated data, I think you actually want [python's `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). With appropriate arguments to the `delimiter` option it will also read space-separated data, or you can replace the spaces with commas before you read the data.

Comment: I don't think `csv` will work here since the data is not tabular and has inconsistent delimiters.

Comment: If by 'not tabular' you mean that it's not a rectangular array of numbers, it actually doesn't matter - `csv` will split each line up into as many tokens as required. It doesn't matter if some lines have more tokens than others. Inconsistent delimiters can be fixed with a per-processing run (replace spaces with commas) before you start.

Comment: By "not tabular" I mean "a row may be split across multiple lines", see the second example. `csv` will do the same thing as his current code and read the data as two rows of three columns each.

Answer (score 1):

The line `for line in open('text.txt', 'r'):` iterates through the lines in the files. It pays no attention to your commas.

If you want to iterate by element instead of by line, you have to use a different loop.

You probably want to read this question: [How to read numbers from file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583573/how-to-read-numbers-from-file-in-python) It shows how to read a number at a time, ignoring line breaks. You'll need to [pass a parameter to the `split` function](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to tell it to skip commas as well as whitespace.

P.S. In your current code, the `if x==2:` does nothing. If you really want to count lines, you need the `enumerate` function.