# Python: convert str to integer

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm new at Python and I have an assginment which is read a file and convert it to matrix. My file is:

```
n 5
0 -- 3
0 -- 4
1 -- 2
1 -- 3
2 -- 4
3 -- 3
```

First of all,I have to make a "5X5" matrix.
I read 5 like this:

```
f = open("graph.txt")
    mylist = f.readlines()
    a = mylist[0][2]
```

When say `print a` it prints 5. In order to make a matrix I need to convert this string to integer. However, when I used `int(a)` function, it remained a `str`. How can I change it to integer permanently?

Comment: You probably also want to look into the `.split()` method to split strings into chunks based on whitespace. That looks like a tool you're going to need.

Comment: What does the resultant matrix look like?  Could you please post it?

Comment: ***Closely related***: [How to read numbers from file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6583573/78845)

Comment: When I use **.split()** for other lines, besides the first one, it splits last number (for example 3) with "3\n". How can I select just one item with this method? @TimPietzcker

Comment: Use `mylist = [line.strip().split() for line in f]`.

Answer (score 3):

`int` creates a new value but does not change the original one. So, to actually change the value, you must do something like

```
list[0][2] = int(list[0][2])
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `int()` constructor to assign to `a`:

```
a = int(list[0][2])
```

Note that this will raise an exception if the string cannot be converted to int.