# How to read numbers in a text file for python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a program where I'm doing simple calculations from numbers stored in a file. However, it keeps on returning a ValueError. Is there something I should change in the code or how the text file is written?

The file is:

```
def main():

    number = 0
    total = 0.0
    highest = 0
    lowest = 0

    try:
        in_file = open("donations.txt", "r")

        for line in in_file:
            donation = float(line)

            if donation > highest:
                highest = donation

            if donation < lowest:
                lowest = donation

            number += 1
            total += donation

            average = total / number

        in_file.close()

        print "The highest amount is $%.2f" %highest
        print "The lowest amount is $%.2f" %lowest
        print "The total donation is $%.2f" %total
        print "The average is $%.2f" %average

    except IOError:
        print "No such file"

    except ValueError:
        print "Non-numeric data found in the file."

    except:
        print "An error occurred."

main()
```

and the text file it is reading of off is

```
John Brown
12.54
Agatha Christie
25.61
Rose White
15.90
John Thomas
4.51
Paul Martin
20.23
```

Comment: What happens when it reads in the "John Brown" line? Seems like you're failing to skip every other line, which is just a name. Where does it define highest the first time though?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read numbers from file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583573/how-to-read-numbers-from-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't read a line, skip to the next one.

```
for line in in_file:
    try:
        donation = float(line)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

Cleaning up your code a bit....

```
with open("donations.txt", "r") as in_file:
    highest = lowest = donation = None
    number = total = 0
    for line in in_file:
        try:
            donation = float(line)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if highest is None or donation > highest:
            highest = donation

        if lowest is None or donation < lowest:
            lowest = donation

        number += 1
        total += donation

        average = total / number

print "The highest amount is $%.2f" %highest
print "The lowest amount is $%.2f" %lowest
print "The total donation is $%.2f" %total
print "The average is $%.2f" %average
```