# read multiple lines of data on one line given x

Tags: python, arrays, list, input, file-io

Im wondering how to use python to read multiple pieces of data based on a given x

In my example I have x = 6 and then on the next line is the x amount of numbers. I want to be able to add it to an array/list or assign vars

```
6
1 2 4 8 10 11
```

Thank you

Comment: Please refer to the answer to ["How to read numbers from file in Python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583573/how-to-read-numbers-from-file-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read numbers from file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583573/how-to-read-numbers-from-file-in-python)

Comment: you can read all line, `split()` elements into list and get 6 elements from list. But you have only 6 elements in line so you get already list with 6 elements.

Comment: So the `6` is kind of redundant? Which would be the point if truth? The `6` or the actual number of numbers?

Comment: @KlausD. it can be challenge created for C/C++/Java which can read single number from file/stream so they may need this 6 to know when to stop reading data.

Comment: @furas No, you would need the number in C or Java. File reading us not *that* bad in these languages.

Comment: Do you want to add sum of those numbers or you want to add separate numbers?