# calculate the average of numbers in each line of a file

Tags: python, loops, file, numbers, average

I want write a program that asks the user for the name of a file containing numbers in each line and prints the average of each line. The numbers in the file are separated by spaces.
The .txt file is the following:

```
    23 55 12 90 42
    56 33 11 76 34
    91 42 45 88 23
    90 114 78 117 89
    116 64 25 77 33
```

I can open and read a file with

```
    f = open(input("File: "))
    for i in f:
```

and with the starting for loop I can loop through the lines. But I don't know how I can only the first line, add the numbers in the first line and then divide it by 5 to get the average and then do it for the remaining lines. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the average of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list)

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider your text file name is "numbers.txt"
you can use the readLines() function like:

```
file1 = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
count = 0

for line in Lines:
    count = 0
    sum_number = 0
    for i in line.split(' '):
        count += 1
        sum_number += int(i)
    print("avg: {}".format(sum_number / count))
```

the output will be:

```
avg: 44.4
avg: 42.0
avg: 57.8
avg: 97.6
avg: 63.0
```

Comment: You could make this even shorter and remove the `count` by using `enumerate`. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [How to read numbers from file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583573/how-to-read-numbers-from-file-in-python)

If you are ok with using Numpy, you could use:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    array = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f]

np.mean(array, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using basic Python

```
with open(input('File: ')) as f:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(f):                     # enumerate provides data and line number for each line
        numbers = [int(i) for i in line.rstrip().split()]  # convert each line to numbers
        avg = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)                    # using definition of average
        print(f'Avg. of line {line_no} is {avg}')          # print line number and average
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
f = open(input("File: "))

for i in f.readlines():
    line = list(map(int, i.strip("\n").split()))
    average = sum(line) / len(line)
    print(average)
```

Basically, the first line gets the file name.

The third line starts a for loop that loops through `f.readlines`, which is basically a list of every line in the file.

The fourth line is a bit confusing. `i.strip("\n").split()` removes the `\n` in every line, and splits the list by space, so you get `['23', '55', '12', '90', '42']`. Then, `list(map(int,` turns each value in this list from a string into an integer.

Finally, the last line gets the average. `sum(line)` adds up every element in the list we just made. Then, `len(line)` gets the number of values in the list. Together, when `sun(line)` is divided by `len(line)` you get the average, which is then printed.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is:

```
name = input('File: ')

with open(name, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

line_nr = 0
for line in lines:
    line_nr += 1
    numbers = line.strip('\n').split(' ')
    sum_numbers = 0
    total_numbers = len(numbers)
    
    for number in numbers:
        int_number = int(number)
        sum_numbers += int_number
        

    

    print(f'The average of line {line_nr} is:', sum_numbers/total_numbers)
```

Output:

```
The average of line 1 is: 44.4
The average of line 2 is: 42.0
The average of line 3 is: 57.8
The average of line 4 is: 97.6
The average of line 5 is: 63.0
```