# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'int'

Tags: python, file-io, io

I'm studying File I/O right now. My input is an integer that contains the size of the number, and the output should be multiple lines containing 10 numbers per line.

```
num = open("final_task2_text.txt")#int(input(''))
var = num.read()

if num > 49:
    print('Number must be below 50!')
else:
    for i in range(0, var):
        print(i, end="•")
        if i % 10 == 9:
            print("")
```

I'm confused because I keep on getting:

> "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'int' "

Comment: `num.read()` returns a `TextIOWrapper`. Did you forget to do a `int()` on it perhaps?

Comment: You want to compare `var` and not `num`. Also, use `int(var)`

Comment: I tried with int(num).read() and it says "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'", and with int(num.read()), it says "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'int'"

Comment: @RenAndyHayag Can you post the contents of the file `final_task2_text.txt`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read numbers from file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583573/how-to-read-numbers-from-file-in-python)

Comment: @RenAndyHayag Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change `num` to `var`. The contents of the file are returned by `num.read()` and it is being stored in `var`. `num` contains the file object, not the file's contents. But this is not it, you need to convert `var` to `int` :

```
num = open("final_task2_text.txt")#int(input(''))
var = int(num.read())

if var > 49:
    print('Number must be below 50!')
else:
    for i in range(0, var):
        print(i, end="•")
        if i % 10 == 9:
            print("")
```

I'd rather recommend using a context manager with the `with` statement and better variable names:

```
with open("final_task2_text.txt") as file:
    number = int(file.read())

    if number > 49:
        print('Number must be below 50!')
    else:
        for i in range(0, number):
            print(i, end="•")
            if i % 10 == 9:
                print("")
```