# [may be duplicate) How to read a number from a file and use it as a variable?

Tags: python

I'm new to python so this is most likely basic knowledge, but how do I read a number from a text file and use it as a variable? I'm trying to make a game where it counts your points and saves it to a plain text file, and when you first run the game it checks for that file and reads the points from your last session. I tried this but it didnt work:

for saving:

```
    def save():
        with open('gameSave.txt', 'w') as f:
            for points in points:
                f.write('%d' % points)
```

for loading:

```
with open("gameSave.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as g:
   points = g.readlines()
```

can anyone help? The points just need to be loaded and save as an integer but i can't figure out how.

Comment: What is `for points in points` supposed to do? Since you recognize that this may be a duplicate, did you try looking for one first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read numbers from file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583573/how-to-read-numbers-from-file-in-python)

Comment: `points = [int(p) for p in g.readlines()]` to restore integer array?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi i dont know what to ask google so i searched some random things but nothing helped me

Comment: @SUTerliakov what it an "integer array"? i stole that code from someone else lol

Answer (score -2, accepted):

##### Store one number only

```py
points = 200

# Store points
f = open("points.txt", "w")
f.write(str(points))
f.close()

# Retrieve them now
f = open("points.txt", "r")
points = int(f.read())
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Write two discrete functions. One to save accumulated points and the other to retrieve what may have previously been saved. Something like this:

```
FILENAME = 'gameSave.txt'

def getSavedPoints():
    try:
        with open(FILENAME) as data:
            return int(data.read())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return 0

def savePoints(points):
    with open(FILENAME, 'w') as data:
        data.write(str(points))

points = getSavedPoints()

# play game and accumulate points

points += 100

savePoints(points)

print(getSavedPoints())
```

So let's assume that no points have previously been saved then the output from this would be:

```
100
```